# trouble deploying django under apache on centos with mod_wsgi

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, python, django, mod-wsgi

EDIT 2:
I got this running mostly!  It was indeed a SELinux issue.   So most things work, I get a cannot write to a read only database error.  And some of my things that seem like static are not found, primarily the /admin isn't seen on anything. I am not sure if it is mysite.settings issue or what.

EDIT:
Thanks to the commenter below I double checked everything and got a new error.    This is progress perhaps, but looks like indeed i have some SELinux policy enabled, and not being a sys-admin by trade, I am not sure where to start looking to figure out what this is telling me.  Here is the apache error_log

```
[Wed May 25 10:08:16.399785 2016] [core:notice] [pid 14935] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Wed May 25 10:08:16.401177 2016] [suexec:notice] [pid 14935] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed May 25 10:08:16.432549 2016] [so:warn] [pid 14935] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.20.0.33. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Wed May 25 10:08:16.438588 2016] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 14935] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed May 25 10:08:16.439945 2016] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 14935] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed May 25 10:08:16.448393 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14935] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 25 10:08:16.448434 2016] [core:notice] [pid 14935] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Wed May 25 10:08:20.102783 2016] [mime_magic:error] [pid 14937] [client 172.20.0.33:59454] AH01512: mod_mime_magic: can't read `/home/sthomas/django_nga_site/mysite/wsgi.py'
[Wed May 25 10:08:20.117380 2016] [:error] [pid 14937] (13)Permission denied: [client 172.20.0.33:59454] mod_wsgi (pid=14937, process='', application='172.20.0.33|/nga_sw'): Call to fopen() failed for '/home/sthomas/django_nga_site/mysite/wsgi.py'.
```

It gives me a 500 error I think if i try to hit the url.

I should add the permissions on the wsgi.py file is:

`-rw-r--r-x`
and the permissions on the folders up through home that the wsgi.py file is in is:

`drwxr-xr-x`

Reading through the questions that may already have my answer, it didn't look like those were the ones so here I am posting in hopes of a lead.

I was trying to use this url:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

my versions:

Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Nov 19 2015 21:43:13

CentOs version:
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

Python Version:
Python 2.7.5

Django version:
(1, 9, 6, 'final', 0)

On a centos box that I do not manage, but I have sudo access to so I was able to install everything needed to get my django app running using the `python manage.py runserver`.  Looked good, so I wanted to tackle the next thing which was getting it to run under apache.

Apache was already serving a static version of my website under /var/www/html   and it was running fine, though I added my own magic for the WSGI stuff to httpd.conf file and loaded the mod_wsgi too I thought.  Though all I get now when hitting the ip address of the url is:

`You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

So I looked back through the httpd.conf and don't try to set (alias?) anything to just / so I am not sure what it is trying to do.

my app is in the folder /home/sthomas under the values there and I thought I had the right chwon and chmod on set on it.

To get this far it took me a while to realize I had to move/del/rename the welcome.conf file that apache had setup to not see the default welcome screen every time I hit my URL (my linux kung-fu is basic)

```
#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/> for detailed information.
# In particular, see 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so 'log/access_log'
# with ServerRoot set to '/www' will be interpreted by the
# server as '/www/log/access_log', where as '/log/access_log' will be
# interpreted as '/log/access_log'.

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
# ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to specify a local disk on the
# Mutex directive, if file-based mutexes are used.  If you wish to share the
# same ServerRoot for multiple httpd daemons, you will need to change at
# least PidFile.
#
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 80

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
#
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User apache
Group apache

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin root@localhost

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
#ServerName www.example.com:80

#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
#DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
DocumentRoot "/var/www"

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
    # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
    # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
    # logged therein and *not* in this file.
    #
    #CustomLog "logs/access_log" common

    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar

    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

#
# "/var/www/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

#
# Specify a default charset for all content served; this enables
# interpretation of all content as UTF-8 by default.  To use the 
# default browser choice (ISO-8859-1), or to allow the META tags
# in HTML content to override this choice, comment out this
# directive:
#
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    #
    # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
    # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
    # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
    #
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
# Defaults if commented: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
#
#EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile on

# Supplemental configuration
#
# Load config files in the "/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf

WSGIScriptAlias /nga_sw /home/sthomas/django_nga_site/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/sthomas/django_nga_site

<Directory /home/sthomas/django_nga_site/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial thoughts would be to check permissions on each level of the directory structure.

It appears that at some point one of the directories does not provide permissions to the apache user which would be executing the django code.

There are a lot of really fantastic posts about this topic already, you may find this one helpful.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386611/django-apache-mod-wsgi-permission-denied

Good luck!

*edit* make sure to check if selinux or similar security service is restricting access.

Comment: oh man that post looks good, I will check it out ty.   I am just not an apache guru but I will check this stuff out, I think I confused myself by how the execution happens in apache and what is running what.   Mostly cause the issue in the logs was it couldn't find the index.html, which is of course true in how Django works?  But I will research up on this it is apparently not as trivial as I had hoped.